# Is there a solution for changing the admin user interface for multiple select attributes in checkboxes?

Tags: magento-1.8

By default, you must hold the Shift or Command key to select multiple values.

The problem is that if you have previously selected values that are not visible (we have very long lists), you might accidentally delete that selection by making a new selection and forgetting to hold the Shift or Command key.

Is there a solution for the selection to be “click on” “click off” instead?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer is no.**

There is no way to better present these on the admin side because, in reality, Magento expects in the backend that these elements are a specific type.

There are many who will laud the use of **checkboxes** to achieve similar functionality but the fact is that when you have to choose from 300+ countries you will be pressed for space and will likely wind up creating a scrolling list anyhow.

So really what you want is the ability to toggle on/off - and unfortunately there really isn't a "nice" way of handling that. [You can install any number](http://loudev.com/) of javascript plugins [that alter the way forms work](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/) - but buyer beware.

I can only really suggest that you add comments to the field on how to use an HTML multiselect box.

[Vinai Kopp has **created a nifty plugin** for annotating/commenting in the Magento admin](https://github.com/Vinai/VinaiKopp_ConfigComments) . You can also create a custom module and in adminhtml.xml you can add comments to any field.

Comment: Hi Philwinkle, thanks for your reply, i am sad now. The multiselect.js from http://loudev.com/ is really great. I hope that somebody can get it working with Magento. I know a very little from PHP.

Comment: It's easy enough to annotate the field on how to use a multiselect, as per my answer. If this has answered your question please mark it as answered. If you need further help, please review and revise your question with additional information and perhaps code snippets of things you've tried so we can be of some further assistance. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, Philwinkle I will try it, when a have something I will show it here, thanks